# Cannot get sbt-plugin nor sbt-play-ebean to work with Play 2.8.0 and sbt 1.5.5

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

Getting back into the Play Framework after a three-year hiatus and trying to start with the latest Play (2.8.0) and sbt (1.5.5).

I am trying to get a project running and receive this message:

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.5 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_41)
[info] loading settings for project global-plugins from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading global plugins from C:\Users\dzell\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.8.0 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-play-ebean:4.0.6 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:2.8.0
```

In my `plugins.sbt` file, I have:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")
```

In my `build.sbt` file, I have:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.6"
```

Running:

```
C:\Users\dzell>java -version
java version "1.8.0_301"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.301-b09, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\dzell>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_41
```

I am guessing there is a version conflict, but not sure how to fix.  I found other posts, but they did not get me the answer:
[Unresolved Dependencies sbt with play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201488/unresolved-dependencies-sbt-with-play-framework)

[Play! Framework and SBT - Problems with ebeans module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074194/play-framework-and-sbt-problems-with-ebeans-module)

[SBT. Resolving dependencies for play sbt-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750999/sbt-resolving-dependencies-for-play-sbt-plugin)

[Unresolved dependency sbt-play-ebean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174421/unresolved-dependency-sbt-play-ebean)

[sbt can not find the ebean dependency (Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095957/sbt-can-not-find-the-ebean-dependency-some-unresolved-dependencies-have-extra-a)

[How to add Play Ebean in Play project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187811/how-to-add-play-ebean-in-play-project?rq=1)

Should I be using just sbt 1.0 and scala 2.12 as it says in the error message?

Appreciate the help - looking forward to getting back into Play.

------------------ EDIT 8/2/2021 - focused on ivy.xml:

As of now, I have the `.ivy2` folder, but there are no folders inside that folder - only a file called `.sbt.ivy.lock`. I tried this URL from the error above and it let me download a file:
https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml

I tried manually creating the folder structure listed in the error:

```
C:\Users\dzell\.ivy2\localcom.typesafe.play\sbt-plugin\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\2.8.0\ivys\ivy.xml
```

I placed the downloaded file in that folder above, but it did not fix the error.

------------------ EDIT 7/29/2021 - adding the full error:

```
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:2.8.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.8.0/sbt-plugin-2.8.0.pom
[error]   not found: C:\Users\dzell\.ivy2\localcom.typesafe.play\sbt-plugin\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\2.8.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-play-ebean;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:4.0.6
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-play-ebean_2.12_1.0/4.0.6/sbt-play-ebean-4.0.6.pom
[error]   not found: C:\Users\dzell\.ivy2\localcom.typesafe.sbt\sbt-play-ebean\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\4.0.6\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-play-ebean/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/4.0.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-play-ebean/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/4.0.6/ivys/ivy.xm
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:258)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$38(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution$$Lambda$4028/4493266.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]         at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:59)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:133)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$$$Lambda$3204/9760435.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:73)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$$$Lambda$3122/23600241.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:146)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$$$Lambda$3206/1799764.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:146)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:127)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$$$Lambda$3200/19618076.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$$$Lambda$2944/32581439.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:160)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$1(Defaults.scala:3678)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$$$Lambda$544/6222801.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at scala.Function1$$Lambda$313/9144307.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater$$Lambda$2811/14105697.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.Execute$$Lambda$2843/26297029.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.Execute$$Lambda$2821/15687584.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$Lambda$2834/23267753.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:2.8.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.8.0/sbt-plugin-2.8.0.pom
[error]   not found: C:\Users\dzell\.ivy2\localcom.typesafe.play\sbt-plugin\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\2.8.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.8.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-play-ebean;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:4.0.6
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-play-ebean_2.12_1.0/4.0.6/sbt-play-ebean-4.0.6.pom
[error]   not found: C:\Users\dzell\.ivy2\localcom.typesafe.sbt\sbt-play-ebean\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\4.0.6\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-play-ebean/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/4.0.6/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty) while downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-play-ebean/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/4.0.6/ivys/ivy.xml
```

Comment: The SBT 1.0 and Scala 2.12 version information is only for plugins (which are always in these versions), you don't need to change version of your project.

Comment: Thanks for the response! My question is how do I get rid of the error when I am trying to get the app to run?  I added the full error to the post above for reference.  Thanks!

Comment: The main error is _InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty_ but this doesn't ring any bell to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not transfer artifact from/to central because of InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278306/could-not-transfer-artifact-from-to-central-because-of-invalidalgorithmparameter)

Comment: I see now what is happening, however, I am not sure where to put this -- `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/security/cacerts` -- does this go in the `build.sbt` (I know I have to change the path to my folder structure)?  Also, the path nor the file -- `C:\Users\dzell\.ivy2\localcom.typesafe.play\sbt-plugin\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\2.8.0\ivys\ivy.xml` -- does not exist, I only have `C:\Users\dzell\.ivy2` folder - appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the Java/JRE/JDK installation, I noticed that there was no `cacerts` file.  I uninstalled the Java/JRE/JDK - making sure all references/folders/files were removed.

I created an Oracle account to download the install files from Oracle's site, since the OpenJDK was giving me issues.

I downloaded and installed the Java/JRE file `jre-8u301-windows-x64.exe` first.  I made sure Java was installed by using the `java -version` in a command prompt.  I was good to go.

I then downloaded and installed the JDK file `jdk-8u301-windows-x64.exe`. I made sure Java was installed by using the `javac -version` in a command prompt.  I was good to go.

I started up sbt and had no problems - it was fixed.